# Cannot GET https API on Window Server 2008 R2

Tags: spring-boot, curl, postman, tls1.2, windows-server-2008-r2

My application need to call some API with https TLS 1.2 endpoint. The application is located in Window Server 2008 R2.

It work fine with Postman but cannot work in Java Spring Boot (JDK 11 + RestTemplate) and also not work with SoapUI and cUrl.

With Java, it throw exeption

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
```

With curl

```
C:\Users\devadmin>curl -v -k https://api.visa.com/
*   Trying 198.217.139.29:443...
* Connected to api.visa.com (198.217.139.29) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to api.visa.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to api.visa.com:443
```

With SoapUI 5.7.0

```
Fri May 20 08:30:44 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Fri May 20 08:30:44 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Sending request: GET /vmorc/offers/v1/all HTTP/1.0
Fri May 20 08:30:44 ICT 2022:DEBUG:I/O error closing connection
   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:245)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.close(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.closeConnection(HttpRequestExecutor.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:297)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:227)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.flush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.flush(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    ... 14 more
   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
Fri May 20 08:30:44 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Closing the connection.
Fri May 20 08:30:44 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Connection closed
Fri May 20 08:30:44 ICT 2022:INFO:I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Fri May 20 08:30:44 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Connection reset
   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.flush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.flush(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:297)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:227)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Fri May 20 08:30:44 ICT 2022:INFO:Retrying request
Fri May 20 08:30:44 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Reopening the direct connection.
Fri May 20 08:30:44 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Attempt 2 to execute request
.......................
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:INFO:Retrying request
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Reopening the direct connection.
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Attempt 4 to execute request
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Sending request: GET /vmorc/offers/v1/all HTTP/1.0
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:DEBUG:I/O error closing connection
   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:245)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.close(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.closeConnection(HttpRequestExecutor.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:297)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:227)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.flush(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.flush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.flush(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:258)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpClientSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    ... 14 more
   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Closing the connection.
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Connection closed
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:DEBUG:Connection shut down
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:ERROR:Exception in request: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:ERROR:An error occurred [Connection reset], see error log for details
Fri May 20 08:30:45 ICT 2022:INFO:Error getting response for [https://api.visa.com.All:Request 1]; java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Openssl in same server

```
C:\openssl\bin>openssl s_client -state -connect api.visa.com:443
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(0000017C)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
163092:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:./ssl/s23_clnt.c:580:
```

openssl in local machine

```
openssl s_client -state -connect api.visa.com:443
CONNECTED(00000084)
SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server hello
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Foster City, O = Visa International Service Association, CN = api.visa.com
verify return:1
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server certificate
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server key exchange
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server certificate request
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server done
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client certificate
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client key exchange
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write finished
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write finished
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read change cipher spec
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read finished
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = California, L = Foster City, O = Visa International Service Association, CN = api.visa.com
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
 1 s:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
 2 s:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = US, ST = California, L = Foster City, O = Visa International Service Association, CN = api.visa.com

issuer=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA

---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
C = US, O = VISA, OU = Visa International Service Association, CN = VI CA1
C = US, O = VISA, OU = Visa International Service Association, CN = Visa Information Delivery External CA
C = US, O = VISA, OU = Visa International Service Association, CN = Visa Information Delivery Root CA
CN = VDPCA, O = VDPVISACA, C = US
CN = VDPCA, O = VDPVISACA, C = US
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4959 bytes and written 452 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 32E83402862CA8E61BB1A07BED75506A42D3AC94963734710F312B79BE05A07F
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 19EE1A9B6873D35D1FDEA404B4E9A830F0E7E1E6AD82CFC700F4C4EBA4238916DF708A8762958977A3FC54350850F61D
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1653039821
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

Add http trace: [http trace](https://github.com/tieudaotu90/common/blob/3be75ef645d11899781f7309b38346ea361eb909/httptrace)

Why it still work with Postman and not work with other ways? And How can I resolve this?

Comment: Check if a connection is possible to any other external service, say `curl -v https://api.mastercard.com/` . Also, in SouapUI, is there any stacktrace after the `SSLException`?

Comment: It may be working with Postman if you have the following: Settings > General > SSL certificate verification set to OFF.  Thus it will not be carrying out a SSL cert check

Comment: Also with your Postman request are you specifying/setting a Request Header Content-Type, if so this may also be required for your curl request.

Comment: @dekkard I was update SoapUI Log in details.   I try with https://www.google.com.vn and it work fine.

Comment: @djmonki In postman the SSL certificate verification set to ON and I dont set any header but it still have a response.

Comment: Visa seems to support only these cipher suites. 
|TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A

More and more it looks like ssl cipher suite provided by client is not on server so its server closed connection.

Comment: Please try `curl -v -k https://api.visa.com/` first and then `openssl s_client -state -connect api.visa.com:443` and attach the output.

Comment: @prasanth Yes, I think window server 2008 not support the ciphers suite of Visa site, but I dont know why Postman still work and how we can fix this.

Comment: @dekkard I was attach output of curl, openssl in same server and openssl in local machine

Comment: Postman is created using electron and nodejs which in turn uses openssl (built in, not system's ). So that is the reason why postman is working.

Comment: What version of JDK11 are you using to run your Spring boot application? Try running it with `logging.level.org.springframework.http=trace` property set and post the exceptions with stacktraces you get in the log when a call to external api is made.

Comment: @dekkard JDK version is 11.0.4. I was attach http trace file as you suggest.

Comment: One last thing to try - in your application change the `https://api.visa.com/vmorc/offers/v1/all?max_offers=1&start_index=1` url to some other for a test, say, `https://sandbox.api.mastercard.com/enhanced/settlement/currencyrate/subscribed/mc-currencies` and see if you get any response (even an error response will do)